# Trying to call range in Array (Lists) in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

```
enter code here


from array import *

# Set up Array
firstArray = array('i', [0,0,0,0,0,0])
secondArray = array("i",[0,0,0,0,0,0])

# Program Greeting
print("This program prompts the client for 6 numbers.")
print("If a number is over 100, move it to a second array.")
print()

# Load numbers from client
for i in range(0,5,1):
    numIn = int(input("Enter a number: ")) == firstArray[i]
    firstArray[i] = numIn

# Move numbers over 100 to 2nd array
print("Searching through the array and moving numbers.")
secArrayCntr = 1
for i in range(0,5,1):
    if firstArray[i] <= 1:
        secondArray[secArrayCntr] = firstArray[i]
        secArrayCntr = secArrayCntr + 1

# Print First Array
print("Displaying the first array.")
for i in range(0,5,1):
    print(firstArray[i])

# Print Second Array
print("Displaying ", secArrayCntr, " numbers over 100.")
for i in range(1, secArrayCntr, 1):
    print(secondArray[i])
```

'''
Dont understand why it displays 0's. If you guys do help, please try and keep the code looking familiar for a novice programmer. Any tips would be great. 
Thank you.

Big_B
'''

'''
P.S.
This is my first post, a tip on adding code to my text box, and not having to add four spaces, manually, would be kinda nice to know.

Comment: Copy and paste the code, highlight the whole code, press ctrl+k, it should format the code... You can check this for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site

Comment: Why are you importing `array` instead of using the built-in `list` type?

Comment: Think you'd probably have better luck with this question on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It displays zeros because you are giving as value a bool which is likely False.

```
numIn = int(input("Enter a number: ")) == firstArray[i]
```

If you want to have the user input number just put that in a variable and than inside the array (you can do it directly if not other operations will happen). Check the following transformation of your code:

```
from array import *

# Set up Array
firstArray = array('i', [0,0,0,0,0,0])
secondArray = array("i",[0,0,0,0,0,0])

# Program Greeting
print("This program prompts the client for 6 numbers.")
print("If a number is over 100, move it to a second array.")
print()

# Load numbers from client
for i in range(0,5,1):
    number = int(input("Enter a number: ")) 
    firstArray[i] = number

# Move numbers over 100 to 2nd array
print("Searching through the array and moving numbers.")
secArrayCntr = 1
for i in range(0,5,1):
    if firstArray[i] > 100: # If it's over 100 than it can't be <1
        secondArray[secArrayCntr] = firstArray[i]
        secArrayCntr = secArrayCntr + 1

# Print First Array
print("Displaying the first array.")
for i in range(0,5,1):
    print(firstArray[i])

# Print Second Array
print("Displaying ", secArrayCntr, " numbers over 100.")
for i in range(1, secArrayCntr, 1):
    print(secondArray[i])
```

, which results in:

```
This program prompts the client for 6 numbers.
If a number is over 100, move it to a second array.

Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 300
Enter a number: 700
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 7
Searching through the array and moving numbers.
Displaying the first array.
3
300
700
4
7
Displaying  3  numbers over 100.
300
700
```

To obtain the numbers over the 100 (as was in one of your comments I had to change this line):

```
if firstArray[i] <= 1:
```

, to this:

```
if firstArray[i] > 100:
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked great. I appreciate the helpful insights.